# Treeview binding in SilverLight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a dynamically generated XML file which i want to bind to a treeview control.
 Here is my code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:TreeView x:Name="tree1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Table }" >
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Skill}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </sdk:TreeView> 
</Grid>
```

My XML is as follows

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Table>
      <skillid>1</skillid>
      <skill>Microsoft</skill>
      <parentid>0</parentid>
      <rating>0</rating>
      <emailid>0</emailid>
   </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

It is generated through a WCF which is returning XElement.

Comment: And? Did you manage? Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the data into objects using `XDocument`:

Sample 1: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/75457.aspx

Sample 2: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/GeneratingTreeViewNodesFromXMLFileInSilverlight3Application08042009142450PM/GeneratingTreeViewNodesFromXMLFileInSilverlight3Application.aspx